# How to filter an nested object array by value in angular expression?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm using an ng-repeat where each object (item) is as below:

```
{
    "properties":
                [
                {"value":"started","key":"status"},
                {"value":"somename","key":"name"},
                {"value":"10","key":"age"},
                ]
}
```

How do I get the value corresponding to key  'status'

I have tried:

```
<span class="badge">{{item.properties['value'] | filter:{item:{properties:{key:'status'}}}}}</span>
```

but no luck.

Thanks,
Rohith

Comment: `item.properties['value']` returns a string. You are then passing that string through angular's `filter` function to match an object structure - this will not work for obvious reasons. Are you just trying to get the value of the item with a given key?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the "value" corresponding to the object which has  "key" = "status"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to filter is `item.properties`, not `item.properties['value']`. This will check each property and return an **array** of items that match your criteria. Since there will only be one match (I assume), you want to grab the resulting `array[0]` and *then* look at the `.value`. You do this by wrapping your filter in parentheses, and then accessing it just like a normal array of objects.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("myCtrl", function () {
  this.items =[{
    "properties":
    [
      {"value":"started","key":"status"},
      {"value":"somename","key":"name"},
      {"value":"10","key":"age"},
    ]
  },{
    "properties":
    [
      {"value":"finished","key":"status"},
      {"value":"somename","key":"name"},
      {"value":"15","key":"age"},
    ]
  },{
    "properties":
    [
      {"value":"error","key":"status"},
      {"value":"somename","key":"name"},
      {"value":"12","key":"age"},
    ]
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as Main">
  <div ng-repeat="item in Main.items">
    <div>{{ (item.properties | filter:{'key': 'status'})[0].value }}</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

## Edit

To implement your own custom filter with nested property searching, you can do something like the following:

Not all of the conditions for partial matching are in there, but it should be enough to get a good idea of how it works.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
.filter("propertyFilter", function () {
  return function (items, property, value, strict) {
    return items.filter(function (item) {
      var propertyChain = property.split(".");
      var _propToCheck = item;
      // step through nested properties
      for(var prop of propertyChain) {
        if (_propToCheck.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          _propToCheck = _propToCheck[prop];
        }
        else {
          // return false if property does not exist
          return false;
        }
      }
      if (strict) {
        // exact matches only
        return _propToCheck === value;
      }
      else {
        // partial matching -- incomplete, but enough to show an example
        if (typeof _propToCheck === "string"){
          return _propToCheck.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        }
        else if (_propToCheck instanceof Array) {
          return _propTocheck.some(function (elem) {
            return _propToCheck.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1;
          })
        }
        else {
          return _propToCheck == value;
        }
      }
    });
  }
})
.controller("myCtrl", function () {
  this.items =[{
    "properties":
    [
      {"value":"started","key":{"internalKey": {"_internalInternalKey": 'status'}}},
      {"value":"somename","key":"name"},
      {"value":"10","key":"age"},
    ]
  },{
    "properties":
    [
      {"value":"finished","key":{"internalKey": "status"}},
      {"value":"somename","key":"name"},
      {"value":"15","key":"age"},
    ]
  },{
    "properties":
    [
      {"value":"error","key":"status"},
      {"value":"somename","key":"name"},
      {"value":"12","key":"age"},
    ]
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as Main">
  <div ng-repeat="item in Main.items" style="margin: 10px;">
    <div>key: {{ (item.properties | propertyFilter:'key':'status')[0].value }}</div>
    <div>key.internalKey: {{ (item.properties | propertyFilter:'key.internalKey':'status')[0].value }}</div>
    <div>key.internalKey._internalInternalKey: {{ (item.properties | propertyFilter:'key.internalKey._internalInternalKey':'status')[0].value }}</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You sir, are a lifesaver. This works perfectly. However, the dot notation still brings some pain, if there are nested objects. Care to throw some light on what is the best way to address nested properties inside 'filter' filter?

Comment: @RohithShenoyG Bracket notation still works for accessing properties. i.e. `item['properties']` and `(...)[0]['value']`. As for nested properties, I would just write a custom filter. It's easy enough, and allows you full control. Would you like me to update my answer demonstrating a custom filter?

Comment: In the interest of gaining some new knowledge, yes. Please do :)

Comment: @RohithShenoyG Updated. Take a look